# stop\start app pool non admin user with powershell remote iis

Tags: powershell, iis, remote-access, remote-server, winrm

I have a script that works remotely with administrator rights,but I want it to work from a domain user who is in the group IIS_USERS , but this user is non-admin user withowt admin rights. UAC disable.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "test-tp" -ScriptBlock { Stop-WebAppPool -Name "Xml" }
$Path = "\\test-tp\bus\web.txt"
while (!(Test-Path $Path)) { Start-Sleep 10 }
If (Test-Path $Path) {Invoke-Command -ComputerName "test-tp" -ScriptBlock { Start-WebAppPool -Name "Bus" }}
```

produces such an error

```
Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-WebItem], UnauthorizedAc
   cessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.IIs
   .PowerShell.Provider.StopItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : test-tp
```

user added to group IIS_USERS + IIS Manager Permission + Remote managment Users + WinRMRemoteWMIUsers.
how to manage iis Non admin user with powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Command as administrator in PowerShell script. UAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248093/run-command-as-administrator-in-powershell-script-uac)

Comment: `invoke-command Credential $user ...`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258134/1701026

Comment: + $user = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $securePass
ord ...
+         
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: To create a PSCredential object, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548976/1701026